# What is known about this power series?

Tags: special-functions

In the course of some calculations, I came across the following powers series.
For fixed $C>1$ let
$$
f_C(u)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{u^k}{C^{k^2}}.
$$
This series converges for all $u\in\mathbb C$, hence $f_C$ is an entire function.
Can it be expressed in terms of classical special functions? Does it satisfy a differential equation? Has anbybody seen this guy somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function has no known expression in terms of common special functions. It is called
"partial theta-function", and there was some recent research on it:
http://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.6262v1.pdf, http://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.1003.pdf,
and literature cited there.

Comment: The corresponding $\sum_{-\infty}^\infty$ would be given in terms of the theta function, as in Carlo's answer.

Comment: And what does it tell you about $f_C(u)$? Only the functional equation $f_C(u)+f_C(-u)=1+\theta_3$ whose solution is not unique.

Answer (score 6):

for $u=C$ it's an elliptic theta function,

$$f_u(u)=1+\frac{1}{2}u^{1/4}\vartheta_2(0,1/u)$$

more generally
$$f_C(e^{2iz})+f_C(e^{-2iz})=1+\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{2kiz}}{C^{k^2}}=1+\vartheta_3(z,1/C)$$

Comment: This is NOT an expression of $f_C(u)$ in terms of theta-function.